# refresh parent page from child's child page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is it possible to refresh parent page from child's child page using  javascript.

I have a webform which opens a child window, a button on child window closes the present child window and opens a subchild window. Now a button on subchild should close the window and refresh the parent form.

Please suggest me the way of doing it.

Thank You.

For button click event

Code in Parent Page

function fun()

```
{
 window.open('Child.aspx');    
 return false;
}
```

Code in child page

function fun()

```
{
 window.close();
 window.open('SubChild.aspx');     
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following in your child window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openwindow()
    {
        opener.document.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```

EDITED

create two files 
1] parent.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openwindow(url)
    {
    window.open(url, "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=no,width=650,height=650");
    }
</script>


<a href="javascript: openwindow('/home/Salil/Desktop/child.html')">Open Child</a>
```

2] child.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openwindow()
    {
        opener.document.location.reload(true);
    }
</SCRIPT>

<a href="javascript: openwindow()">Refresh Parent</a>
```

EDITED LATEST

write a function in child1.html

```
function child1()
    {
        opener.document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

call that function form child2.html as follows

```
function child2()
{
    window.opener.child1();

}
```

Comment: Is it before opening SubChild Window?

Comment: check my EDITED version & open parent.html in browser & then test.

Comment: I wanted to refresh parent from child's child window

Comment: Please check my EDITED LATEST Answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using these?

window.opener.reload();

window.opener.location.reload();

I think window.opener.opener.reload(); may work..

Comment: Ya, I used them. But it is valid only for one patent-child.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after seeing your code.  The problem is you're opening the 2nd window from the 1st window and closing the 1st window so you have no reference back to the opener.  You can instead call a method in your Parent window to open the 2nd window, that way the Parent is still your opener.

**Parent.html**

```
function openWindow(sURL){
  window.open(sURL);
}
```

**Child1.html**

```
function fun(){
  window.opener.openWindow('Child2.html');     
  window.close();
}
```

**Child2.html**

```
function fun(){
  window.opener.location.reload(true);     
}
```

Comment: Its giving error.
"Breaking at jscript runtime. Access Denaied"